# Converting .xls data to Python data types to be used as an input of a Tensorflow Lite model

Tags: python, numpy, tf.keras, tensorflow-lite

I've captured and saved accelerometer values to an xls worksheet. I want to use these as an input to a Tensorflow Lite model but I'm struggling to do the required data conversions.

A simplified snippet from the workbook would be [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoTGV.png)

In this simplification there are five pieces of training data, each with eight sampled values for the x, y and z planes. There is also an output value.

From here I want to effectively create the following:

```
typedef struct  
{  
  s16 XInput[8];  
  s16 YInput[8];  
  s16 ZInput[8];  
}sInputData_t;  

sInputData_t Inputs[5];  

u8 Outputs[5];
```

And populate `Inputs` and `Outputs`with values from the xls file.

I've managed to get as far as opening the workbook using xls:

`xls = pd.read_excel('TestVals.xls', header=None)`

But it's the subsequent code which I'm struggling with. After the conversions are done I want to create the TensorFlow Lite model with like this:

```
model = create_model()
model.fit(Inputs, Outputs);
```

In a nutshell I need to replace `***** Convert data here *****` with actual code:

```
xls = pd.read_excel('TestVals.xls', header=None)

// ***** Convert data here *****

model = create_model()
model.fit(Inputs, Outputs);
```